# Generic interfaces and wildcards

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

So, i have here this little class hierarchy:

```
public class Tst2 {
    /** interface allowing copying */
    private interface Copyable<T> {
        void copyFrom(T original);
    }

    /** Class which can be parameterized by types which can self-copy so it can copy those objects when it needs */
    private static class Manager<T extends Copyable<T>> {
        T value;

        Manager(final T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        void someWork() {
            value.copyFrom(value);
        }
    }

    /** and here's one example of the self-copying class for Manager to manipulate */
    private static class Box<T> implements Copyable<Box<T>> {
        T value;

        Box(final T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        T getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        void setValue(final T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public void copyFrom(Box<T> original) {
            this.setValue(original.getValue());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box<Object> objBox = new Box<Object>("object value");
        Manager<Box<Object>> objectManager = new Manager<>(objBox); // we have manager of Boxes with Objects
        objectManager.someWork();

        Box<String> strBox = new Box<String>("string value");
        Manager<Box<String>> stringManager = new Manager<>(strBox); // and here's manager of Boxes with Strings
        stringManager.someWork();   // all works well
    }
}
```

It all works beautifully. And yes, you can probably write it differently, but i like this particular way of doing it - it's concise and delivers everything i want.

So i can create `Manager<Box<String>>` and every other concrete implementation, perfect.
So now let's try creating a manager of ANY Box by declaring variable:

```
Manager<Box<?>> anyManager;
```

with the idea of doing something like the following later:

```
anyManager = (Manager<Box<?>>) (Manager<?>) new Manager<Box<Object>>(objBox);
```

Ooops, the problem with DECLARING the variable(i'm not doing any casting just yet):

```
Error:(52, 20) java: type argument Tst2.Box<?> is not within bounds of type-variable T
```

So you can't create any `Manager<Box<?>>`! But surely ANY Box implements Copyable, so it should fit in that

```
class Manager<T extends Copyable<T>>
```

Right?
I guess it doesn't consider the fact that all of my Boxes implement copyable of the same type of Box, so it thinks that that wildcard can be from different boxes, or something like that?

Can someone please explain it and/or suggest a workaround?
Again - i'm not interested in someone rewriting the whole solution, i'm interested in fixing this particular bit only. Or, at least, explaining what's going on.

Comment: What's the idea with the double cast?

Comment: The idea with having Manager<Box<?>> is that it's sometimes more convenient to use it instead of Manager<Box<Object> while being (logically) equivalent. I'm happy to have it without double-cast if you can do it. But the problem is not with the doublecast, the problem is that you can't even DECLARE the variable with the type Manager<Box<?>> - it's just an illegal type.

Comment: There's nothing illegal about a `Foo<Bar<?>>` type of generic variable. It just limits things because of the "half-assed" generics, when you've got almost typesafety, but then you stick that wildcard in the end.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understood you right - you mean it's a fault of javas type system which is not smart enough? If so then it looks that way for me too, but there should be some way to still workaround it, I would hope.

Comment: Well, using wildcards is rarely a good idea, but I'm not so internally familiar with these sorts of special cases to know what are the particularities involved here.

Comment: And in this case it's not about any general `Foo<Bar<?>>` type, which is of course legal. But about that particular `Manager<Box<?>>` which is different as Manager adds additional restrictions on its parameter, which should be legal according to the common sense(i guess), but it's not legal in practice for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

This is either a bug in javac or ecj, usually ecj is correct in these cases.

But one could argue that:

Copyable<Box<?>> is not a supertype of Box<?> (even ecj will tell you). But thats what the type bound on Manager requires when you replace T with Box<?>.

Comment: Exactly, apparently it's not. But logically - it should be, isn't it? I guess it thinks that those ? are different somehow, but they're captured within the same T! `class Box<T> implements Copyable<Box<T>>` And it happens in javac.